# Mixing and monitoring separate livestream audio channels

Tags: mixing, gameaudio, monitoring, computer, streaming

I have been doing live streaming of video games on Twitch.tv as of recently. I have a decent setup, and I am getting all the audio and video that I need to stream through a program called OBS (Open Broadcast Software).

I have a few audio components that I need to capture, one being my PC, one being the microphone on my headset (wireless, USB, Corsair Vengeance 2100), and one being the Playstation 4, which is being captured with an Elgato Game Capture device, which plugs in to the PC via USB.

Right now all the sounds come through my headset so that I can hear them, and they also get pumped through the regular windows audio service, so I could plug speakers in to a line-in and hear everything as well.

**Is there some way that I can plug everything into a hub of sorts, so that I can control the volume of the audio playing through my headset, separate from the audio that goes to the streaming program?**

The reason being that when I have the volumes of everything loud enough that they are nice in the stream, they are really loud in my headset. So I want to turn them down in the headset, but not change the volume in the stream.

It seems like if I could plug it all into a *hub*, then from that, plug in via USB to my PC, and also have my headset dongle from the hub, then I would basically have 2 channels, one would send audio to my PC like normal, and the other would send audio to the dongle for my headset. So in essence the headset is no longer plugged in to the computer getting sound from that, but rather getting the sound directly from the *hub*.

Sorry for the long post, just trying to give as much detail as possible. Hopefully it all makes sense, I am completely open to questions, suggestions, and criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a headphone amp or similar device that includes a volume control, so you can adjust the volume of your headphones independently.

For a more robust and flexible setup you can use a mixer (hardware or software).

Comment: Thanks, I will try some of these options and see where I get.